# Service Generated from WSDL Returns Different WSDL

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl, datacontract

I have generated a WCF service interface from a **delivered WSDL** schema, this interface have then been implemented in one of my WCF services without any problems.

```
[ServiceBehavior(Name = "HL7Service", Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3")]
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:hl7-org:v3", Name = "HL7Service", SessionMode = SessionMode.Allowed)]
public class HL7Service : IPatientRegistryQueryTracker_Binding
{


    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = false, IsInitiating = true, IsOneWay = false, AsyncPattern = false, Action = "PRPA_IN201302NO_Operation")]
    public PRPA_IN201302NOResponse PRPA_IN201302NO_Operation(PRPA_IN201302NO request)
    {

    }

    [OperationContract(IsTerminating = false, IsInitiating = true, IsOneWay = false, AsyncPattern = false, Action = "PRPA_IN201304NO_Operation")]
    public PRPA_IN201304NOResponse PRPA_IN201304NO_Operation(PRPA_IN201304NO request)
    {

    }

}
```

The strange part is that the WSDL from my new service do not comply to the WSDL it was generated from?

Example on how a part of the **delivered WSDL** lookt like

```
    <xs:complexType name="PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="InfrastructureRootElements"/>
        <xs:element name="id" type="PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient.id" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="addr" type="AD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="telecom" type="TEL" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="statusCode" type="PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient.statusCode"/>
        <xs:element name="effectiveTime" type="IVL_TS" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="confidentialityCode" type="CE" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="veryImportantPersonCode" type="CE" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="patientPerson" type="PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient.patientPerson" nillable="true"/>
            <xs:element name="patientNonPersonLivingSubject" type="PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient.patientNonPersonLivingSubject" nillable="true"/>
        </xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="providerOrganization" type="COCT_MT150003UV03.Organization" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="subjectOf" type="PRPA_MT201302UV02.Subject4" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element name="coveredPartyOf" type="PRPA_MT201302UV02.CoveredParty" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="InfrastructureRootAttributes"/>
    <xs:attribute name="nullFlavor" type="NullFlavor" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="classCode" type="RoleClass" use="required" fixed="PAT"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

This is generated to the following interface to my service

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("patientNonPersonLivingSubject", typeof(PRPA_MT201302UV02PatientpatientNonPersonLivingSubject), IsNullable=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("patientPerson", typeof(PRPA_MT201302UV02PatientpatientPerson), IsNullable=true)]
public object Item {
    get {
        return this.itemField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemField = value;
    }
}
```

This simes okay. This is how the same part looks from my service WSDL.

```
<xs:complexType name="PRPA_MT201302UV02Patient">
−
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="addrField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfAD"/>
    <xs:element name="classCodeField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="confidentialityCodeField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfCE"/>
    <xs:element name="coveredPartyOfField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPRPA_MT201302UV02CoveredParty"/>
    <xs:element name="effectiveTimeField" nillable="true" type="tns:IVL_TS"/>
    <xs:element name="idField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPRPA_MT201302UV02Patientid"/>
    <xs:element name="itemField" nillable="true" type="xs:anyType"/>
    <xs:element name="nullFlavorField" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="providerOrganizationField" nillable="true" type="tns:COCT_MT150003UV03Organization"/>
    <xs:element name="realmCodeField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfCS"/>
    <xs:element name="statusCodeField" nillable="true" type="tns:PRPA_MT201302UV02PatientstatusCode"/>
    <xs:element name="subjectOfField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfPRPA_MT201302UV02Subject4"/>
    <xs:element name="telecomField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfTEL"/>
    <xs:element name="templateIdField" nillable="true" type="tns:ArrayOfII"/>
    <xs:element name="typeIdField" nillable="true" type="tns:II"/>
    <xs:element name="veryImportantPersonCodeField" nillable="true" type="tns:CE"/>
</xs:sequence>
```

The choice element are replaced with a simple anyType element? And the problem with this is that the types(PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient.patientPerson and PRPA_MT201302UV02.Patient.patientNonPersonLivingSubject) that are suppose to be placed on itemfield is never generated in the client proxy class?

I have tried to generate the proxy client classes from the **delivered WSDL** schema that the service are generated from and this will create a correct proxy client, BUT when trying to communicate with the service there will be an Datacontract missmatch exception

Why is not the WSDL schema the same?

Comment: Why would it be the same? One is being generated, the other is in a file. If you want it to be the same, then you should have WCF return the WSDL from the file.

Comment: IF the WCF service implement a interface that are generated from MySchemaA.WSDL, then I would expect the service to follow this WSDL and thereby render its own WSDL exacly the same.

How can I let my service provide MySchemaA.WSDL intead of its own? And will this really mather? Should the exception not be the same?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. That's especially true since your WSDL uses complex features that strain interoperability. xs:group, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are marking the class with the operational contract instead of the contract (Interface).

Also you do not show if you have marked your messages with DataContract / DataMember attribute.